# Using interface driven approach or static helper methods

Tags: c#

I am using Dapper ORM in the application. I have created an interface with Dapper methods, to have a quick glance for anyone which functions of Dapper is being used in this application  and can easily be replaced by other ORM by implementing it.

```
public interface IDapperRepository
{            
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>(string query, object cmdParams = null, CommandType cmdType = CommandType.Text) where T : class;
    T GetById<T>(string query, object cmdParams = null, CommandType cmdType = CommandType.Text) where T : class;
}   


class DapperRepository : IDapperRepository
{   
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>(string query, object cmdParams = null, CommandType cmdType = CommandType.Text) where T : class
    {
        //implementation
    }

    public T GetById<T>(string query, object cmdParams = null, CommandType cmdType = CommandType.Text) where T : class
    {
        //implementation
    }
}
```

From DAL Layer:

```
public class UserRep : IUserRep
{
    private readonly IDapperRepository _iDapperRepository;
    public UserRep()
    {
         _iDapperRepository = new DapperRepository();
    }

    public IEnumerable<UserBO> GetAll()
    {
          return _iDapperRepository.GetAll<UserBO>("select * from users");
    }
    //Other methods
}
```

In the users list page, _iUserRep.GetAll() gets called from controller.

From above code, by calling _iUserRep.GetAll() or any other method in the repository classes, DapperRepository class gets instantiated. My question is since I have only utility methods in the DapperRepository class, is it good idea to remove the IDapperRepository and modify DapperRepository as "static" with "static" methods, so that I can call the methods without instantiating it. I would like to know whether there would be any performance gain by doing so.

Also, any inputs to improve this design is appreciated.

Comment: You mentioned *controller*, are you working at ASP.MVC application ?

Comment: Yes, it is an MVC application. Since it is more of design question, I didn't specify much about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is question about preferable conception, I'll present what I'd do. First of all try to limit your abstractions and overhead complexity - simplify first, automate last. Is there any chance that you will be changing repository implementation for usage of different ORM ? If don't, don't use such approach. It's old school repository style which seems okay, at first glance, but in the end is revalued and redundant - in my opinion at least. As it is ASP.MVC application, you can try using commands instead:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    public IDocumentSession DocumentSession { get; set; }

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        DocumentSession = ...OpenSession(); // initialize and open session
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.IsChildAction)
        {
            return;
        }

        using (DocumentSession)
        {
            if (filterContext.Exception != null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (DocumentSession != null)
            {
                DocumentSession.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    public void ExecuteCommand(Command cmd)
    {
        cmd.DocumentSession = DocumentSession;
        cmd.Execute();
    }

    public TResult ExecuteCommand<TResult>(Command<TResult> cmd)
    {
        ExecuteCommand((Command)cmd);
        return cmd.Result;
    }
}
```

Abstract commands definition:

```
public abstract class Command
{
    public IDocumentSession DocumentSession { get; set; }

    public abstract void Execute();
}

public abstract class Command<T> : Command
{
    public T Result { get; protected set; }
}
```

Example command implementation:

```
public class GetUsers : Command<IList<User>>
{
    public IList<int> IDs { get; set; }

    public override void Execute()
    {
        return DocumentSession.Query<User>()...;
    }
}
```

Usage - execution form controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
public NJsonResult GetUsers(string ids)
{
    var result = ExecuteCommand(new GetUsers
                                    {
                                        IDs = ids
                                    });
    //...
}
```

It's not a trivial problem in my opinion. Need quite a lot of consideration. For better understanding o it, you can try to go through Ayende's blog in your free time:

http://ayende.com/blog/4784/architecting-in-the-pit-of-doom-the-evils-of-the-repository-abstraction-layer

along with the series below (short posts, really quick to go through):

http://ayende.com/blog/153889/limit-your-abstractions-analyzing-a-ddd-application

http://ayende.com/blog/153921/limit-your-abstractions-application-eventsndash-what-about-change

http://ayende.com/blog/153953/limit-your-abstractions-application-eventsndash-proposed-solution-1

http://ayende.com/blog/153985/limiting-your-abstractions-reflections-on-the-interface-segregation-principle

http://ayende.com/blog/154017/limit-your-abstractions-application-eventsndash-proposed-solution-2ndash-cohesion

http://ayende.com/blog/154049/limit-your-abstractions-application-eventsndash-event-processing-and-rx

... and from here it is starting to be more interesting:

http://ayende.com/blog/154081/limit-your-abstractions-you-only-get-six-to-a-dozen-in-the-entire-app

http://ayende.com/blog/154113/limit-your-abstractions-commands-vs-tasks-did-you-forget-the-workflow

http://ayende.com/blog/154145/limit-your-abstractions-all-cookies-looks-the-same-to-the-cookie-cutter

http://ayende.com/blog/154177/limit-your-abstractions-so-what-is-the-whole-big-deal-about

http://ayende.com/blog/154209/limit-your-abstractions-refactoring-toward-reduced-abstractions

http://ayende.com/blog/154241/limit-your-abstractions-the-key-is-in-the-infrastructurehellip

http://ayende.com/blog/154273/limit-your-abstractions-and-how-do-you-handle-testing

I hope it gives you alternative look at this topic.

Comment: Thanks for series of articles. Seems it is a completely different design. As per now, I will have to stick to this as I am almost done with the application. I asked this question for code refactoring.